# How do I save the username value to a cookie so I can retrieve it if the user wants to be remembered?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies

I am trying to implement a "Remember Me" for the username in a login page using cookies.

I am trying to do this by using Values.Add on the cookie object:

```
 ck.Values.Add("username", txtUName.Value);
```

However, when I add a value in this way, authentication breaks. (If I remove the line authentication works again.)

How can I keep the username stored in the cookie without breaking it?

The full code for this bit is:

```
            bool IsRemember = chkPersistCookie.Checked;

            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;

            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUName.Value, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), IsRemember, "your custom data");

            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);

            ck = new HttpCookie("MYCOOKIEAPP", cookiestr);

            if (IsRemember)
            {
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
                ck.Values.Add("username", txtUName.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                ck.Values.Add("username", txtUName.Value);
                ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

            }

            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

Comment: Please change the question title, seems it not the actual question !

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get what I needed direct from the FormsAuthenticationTicket:

```
  if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value); 


               txtUName.Value = ticket.Name;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this example from [here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/) and read what they write. I test it in my test project and it works.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"] != null)
    {
        ColorSelector.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"].Value;
        BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
    }
}

protected void ColorSelector_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("BackgroundColor");
    cookie.Value = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```